# MTP device acess denied

Tags: linux, mtp

I'm using linux kde, I was able to use mtp device on it but recently I'm facing problem error is mtp device access denied but it working with kde connect. How I can get rid it of ? I had also checked with live media if driver is corrupted but problem is still same.

Comment: What linux distro and version are you using? What kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have rebooted the device and are not forgetting to activate MTP on each connection from the notification drop-down which is required on Marshmallow and newer Android OSes, it is likely that your Media Storage and External Storage databases are out of sync and not updating properly.

*Note that none of the following actions deletes or modifies your files, pictures, or other data, just the databases that index those files are forced to be rebuilt.*

Disconnect the USB cable, although the exact menu entries could vary by OEM, here are some general instructions on how to rebuilt those databases... Go to Settings - Apps and tap the 3-dot menu and select Show System. Then scroll through and find External Storage and tap into it, then select Storage, and inside that select Clear Data and Clear Cache, then press back twice to the main Apps menu and scroll down to Media Storage and perform the same action. Go home and reboot. DO NOT CONNECT THE USB cable at this time, once the phone is rebooted and the startup appears complete, wait at least 5-10 minutes (the databases are rebuilding in the background, without watching the logcat there is no way to see if they are complete, sometimes it is a quick process and sometimes it can take 30+ minutes depending on your device and number of files), then connect the USB cable and the folders and files should appear.

If this doesn't work, your issue is likely not Android related but a permissions or setup issue in your Linux distro with your user, and that question would be more suited to the Super User, Ask Ubuntu, or Unix & Linux sites.

Comment: I'm using ics phone, I don't think there any issue with pc because I've already checked with live bootable and there problem still remained.